# Returning only one column from a FILTER function

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I'm trying out the new FILTER function in Excel, and it seems to mostly work the same as in Google Sheets. One thing I haven't figured out, however, is if there's anything analogous to Sheet's QUERY function. I can generate a FILTER fine, but I don't know how to only display one column of the result. In the example below, I only want to show the second column of the FILTER result.

Is there a simple solution to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
=FILTER($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7 = D2)
```

The first criterion is the output range and the second criterion is the Boolean.  The caveat is that the ranges must be the same size and shape.

If more than one is wanted we multiply or add for And or Or respectively two Boolean.

[image]

Comment: Is this the first Q&A where both are specifically about the new functions? Legit.